# Can shared-mime-info associate a MIME type to a desktop applications?

Tags: mime-types, freedesktop

I can add a new MIME type in shared MIME-info, but how can I associates this MIME type with an application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you just want to associate them directly, and not make them default, you can add them to

```
/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
```

(system-wide), or

```
~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
```

(per-user).

edit: using `xdg-mime`, as geekosaur suggests, might perhaps be more robust.  In this case, you would want

> `xdg-mime install [--mode mode]
>   [--novendor] mimetypes-file`
>
> Adds the file type descriptions
>   provided in `mimetypes-file` to the
>   desktop environment.  `mimetypes-file`
>   must be a XML file that follows the
>   freedesktop.org Shared MIME-info
>   Database specification and that has a
>   mime-info element as its document
>   root. For each new file type one or
>   more  icons with name major-minor must
>   be installed with the
>   `xdg-icon-resource` command in the
>   mimetypes context. For example the
>   `application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text`
>   filetype requires an icon by the name
>   of `application-vnd.oasis.opendocument.text`
>   to be installed.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `xdg-mime` command.

> `xdg-mime default` *application mimetype*
>
> Ask the desktop environment to make *application* the default application for opening
>      files of type *mimetype*. An application can be made the default for several file
>      types by specifying multiple *mimetype* s.

The above is taken from `man xdg-mime`, slightly modified to copy the usage down from the **SYNOPSIS**.